# Getting Error in if (mydata[row1 - 1, col2] == "Has") { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed but not applicable?

Tags: r

I italicized the line of code in question. I am getting this error but it does not make much sense. I am merely having it scan to see if the "x" is there and add 1 to the inf1 IF it is there, for each time it sees it there. Yet, for some reason it is interpreting it differently?

Comment: Add `message("i: ", row1-1, ", j: ", col2, ", subset: ", mydata[row1-1,col2])` inside the loop before the `if` condition to see what is going on.

Comment: I am confused on what you mean, sorry

Comment: I was trying to teach you some basic debugging skills.

Answer (score 1):

Observe your initial code creates a matrix of `NA` values, e.g.

```
timesteps = 3
pop = 5
mydata <- matrix(nrow=timesteps, ncol=pop)

mydata
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
[2,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
[3,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
```

Your next 2 lines of code creates values for the first row of your matrix:

```
mydata[1,1] <- "Has"  
for (col1 in 2:pop){mydata[1,col1] <- "S"}

mydata
    [,1]  [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,] "Has" "S"  "S"  "S"  "S" 
[2,] NA    NA   NA   NA   NA  
[3,] NA    NA   NA   NA   NA
```

Your error comes in the for loop when `row1 > 2`. Here you are indexing to a `NA` value in your matrix and asking if `NA == "Has"`, which produces `NA` -- a missing value rather than `TRUE|FALSE`, e.g.

```
row1=3
col2=1

mydata[row1-1,col2]
[1] NA

mydata[row1-1,col2] == "Has"
[1] NA
```

I believe your matrix is not properly constructed.

Comment: @klox It looks like what you need is a reference matrix that has the values "Has", "Har", "Hss", "Hsr", "Es", "Er" that you are checking for equivalence in your if statement, where is this reference matrix? Based on this reference matrix, you are filling out a vector of equivalent length dealing with infection rates. Perhaps you can edit your question and explain what your desired output would be.

Comment: You created a `mydata` matrix that is NA, that is not a reference matrix. There is nothing that contains  "Has", "Har", "Hss", "Hsr", "Es", "Er" to compare to in your if statement. E.g. Your if statement says if an element in my matrix is equivalent "Es" then do this, but you have an NA matrix so nothing will be equivalent to "Es".

Comment: What is the purpose of your if statement? You need to have a reference for comparison. What is this line for? `if (mydata[row1-1,col2] == "Har")` when `mydata` is *initially* empty you are basically testing `if (NA == "Har)` which will always return `NA`.  This happens before it gets to the point which you say your code fills up the output matrix.  Sorry I can't help you more, I think you need to break down your code in simpler chunks that you can debug.